# Block access to certain websites from other computers on shared internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, connection-sharing

I have very little knowledge about networking. I have an internet connection on my PC (running Windows XP). I've enabled internet connection sharing to other computers on my network connected using a WIFI router.

I want to block use of GMail (in general, specific domains) from other computers, but should be able to access them from my own machine.

I can't edit my hosts file because my machine too would lose access. I guess I need to configure my wireless router for that. But I have no idea how to do so. My wireless router is a Zyxel P-660HW-T1 v2.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I really don't think preventing uploading is possible. And it's definitely not a networking problem. Your best (and possibly only) shot is asking your users not to do it.

Comment: @m4573r Is it possible to block specific domains or IPs in the router?

Comment: According to the [manual](ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/P-660HW-T1_v2/user_guide/P-660HW-T1%20v2_3.40.pdf) it's possible, but as you're behind the router, you will block yourself as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IE, go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security tab. Click on Restriced Sites, and you can add that domain / whatever websites there (I imagine there are similar features in other browsers). This, however, depends on other using not messing with these settins, or disabling their access to edit such features.